# Rad Studio XE __property set method not working

Tags: c++, properties, c++builder, rad

The following is an example code out of a header file (missing constructors):

```
class MyItem
{
   // blah blah
};

class MyClass
{
  public:
  __property MyItem Item = {read=GetItem, write=SetItem};

   private
   MyItem FItem;
   MyItem GetItem(void);
   void SetItem(const MyItem AItem);

}
```

And in the cpp file:

```
void MyClass::SetItem(const MyItem AItem)
{
   FItem = AItem;    
}
```

I've excluded the get method because that works fine.

For some reason the set method does not work.

I am definitely assigning a value to the property in some test code.

If I attempt to place a break point in the set method it won't place it because the code has been optimised out because it is never called.

If I replace the Set method with the field variable itself it gets written to fine.

I've gone through all the documentation supplied with XE.

I am confused to the point where I think it may be a compiler bug.

It makes no difference if I pass the arguments in by reference.

Ideas?

Comment: Hmm..  what happens if you put a breakpoint on the property set and single-step, (step into)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved after having some sleep.

I was never actually setting the class itself, I was setting a member of the class, so it was actually using the get method then adjusting the value that was returned.

Changing the return to be a return by reference solved my problem.

The fact that it worked when I directly assigned the property to the Field must of been because the compiler simply substitutes the field for the property name at compile time. My actual application has various fields that would be set depending on the class's state, hence why leaving it this way was not an option.

Thanks